# Cmd line escape characters

Tags: kubernetes, cmd, windows-10

I'm translating a service manual from Linux to Windows command line, and running into some issues with escape characters. After looking at other entries here and general googling I haven't been able to find anything that works for whatever reason.

In this line:

> ```
> kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "demo-registry"}]}' -n testNamespace
> ```

I'm unable to find a combination of `` ` ``, `^`, or `\` that allows me to escape the double quotes. I was able to get it to work in the powershell command below though.

> ```
> kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p "{\`"imagePullSecrets\`": [{\`"name\`": \`"demo-registry\`"}]}" -n testNamespace
> ```

Comment: just to confirm: you want to avoid that double quotes and you don't like your last command as it looks like?

Comment: There is nothing special in the command line that would require escaping by `^` in the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`…

Comment: The latter command only works in PowerShell. As it turns out the problem not with cmd but with the server receiving the command.

Answer (score 1):

Inverting the " and 's around the inputs allows the command to run without needing escape characters. The errors I had received were in part due to issues with my local environment.

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p "{'imagePullSecrets': [{'name': 'demo-registry'}]}" -n testNamespace
```